# Scope of stubing any_instance in mocha gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, stub

I wrote test case for my rails app to check whether a user is connected to facebook or not. For that purpose i need to stub a method in my rails app otherwise it gave me an error. 
So i used

```
SocialNet::Facebook.any_instance.stubs(:status).returns(true)
```

If i wrote this line in my test cases like

```
test 'z' do
   SocialNet::Facebook.any_instance.stubs(:status).returns(true)
   # testing code
end
```

And run the command

> ruby -I test test/integration/erp_flows_test.rb -n test_z.

Then it works fine but if i place

`SocialNet::Facebook.any_instance.stubs(:status).returns(true)`

in **test_helper** file in **def self.prepare metho**d. Then running same command for test case works well. But if i run the all test cases in my file by command `ruby -I test test/integration/erp_flows_test.rb` then it did not work.

Does that means

> SocialNet::Facebook.any_instance.stubs(:status).returns(true) have
>   limited scope in only test case? What exactly i am doing wrong

I am using Minitest for testing purpose

Answer (score 0):

It's tough from what you've given to answer the question.

It isn't clear what class or module you are defining in `test_helper.rb` that has a `prepare` class method.  Have you verified that the method was called?

Here's something that RSpec::Mock has to say about using their version of `any_instance` stubs: [any_instance](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance).  In particular,

> "Using this feature is often a design smell. It may be that your test is trying to do too much or that the object under test is too complex."

It's better to have an instance (not any-old), and stub the method on the instance.